# Family birth probability question

Tags: probability

Assume the probability is 1/2 that a child born is a girl. If a family has three children what is the probability:

a) of getting exactly one girl?

b) of getting at most two girls?

Please give answer and explanation. So I can learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possiblilies are the following:

(Let boy be denoted by B and girl denoted by G)

BBB

BBG

BGB

GBB

GBG

GGG

BGG

GGB

So, $P(\text{exactly one girl})=\frac{3}{8}$

and

$P(\text{at most two girls})=P(0)+P(1)+P(2)=\frac{1}{8}+\frac{3}{8}+\frac{3}{8} =\frac{7}{8}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  There are eight possibilities, so list them all and count.  Then read up on [Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) to see how to solve it with higher numbers.  You want the row $1\ 3\ 3\ 1$ for your problem.